# How to pass the error message server side to client side using mvc and ajax format

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, exception, error-handling

I need some work follow as:

1. I pass the some value client side to server side (mvc format using ajax)
2. Check the value in my controller after some action, its need to return the checked id not found in my client side ( this 1 st error message).
3. If this condition is true means check the another condition's in next step.
4. In this condition check the value give the message for client like " would you like perform the id for same student 'yes' yes to all' 'no' 'no to all'.
5. using the this click action i ll do the next action.

[  i am very confuse in 4 and 5th step] .My just sample code brackets given below, please forward your big knowledge. i know this is tuff one . Thank you

My code:

```
     public ActionResult Action(parameters)
     {
            foreach (var seletedid in id)
            {
                // my code
            }    

            if (1st condition )
            {    
                return Json(new { success = false }); 
                // 1st error message i use like this
                // after that the preform goes to the end
            }
              try
            {                   
                foreach (some code)
                {                      
                  // my code
                    if (2nd condtion (3 point))
                    {
                     // using this i perform the some action herer 
                     }    
                }
           }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {    
                  return null;
              }
              return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On First button click call Function below:

```
    function MyFunction() {
        $.post('@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")', { pareter1: value1, pareter2:     value2 }, function (json) {
            if (json.Status) {
                var confirm = confirm("would you like perform the id for same student?");
            if (confirm) {
                $.post('@Url.Action("SecondAction", "Controller")', { pareter3: value3, pareter4: value4 }, function (result) {
                    //check the condition and proceed here, if needed.
                });
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

If you are using:

```
Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "SuccessNotification" })
```

Then do:

```
function SuccessNotification(json) {
        if (json.Status) {
            var confirm = confirm("would you like perform the id for same student?");
            if (confirm) {
                $.post('@Url.Action("SectionAction", "Controller")', { pareter3:     value3, pareter4: value4 }, function (result) {
                    //check the condition and proceed here, if needed.
                });
            }
        }

    }
```

SuccessNotification will be called when something will be returned from server side. Here you can check the return data and based on you condition you can call next method.

Comment: how to pass teh data server to client first?

Comment: return Json(new { success = false }); will return data to client side. You can add number of parameter here. Like: return Json(new { success = false,Message="Validated Successfully" }) and can get these outputs on success method. eg: in SuccessNotification(json): json.success and json.Message

Comment: thank you its useful. But i am mainly struggle in server side. in my code  if (1st condition ) after that how to pass the value(unselected id) .here i ma just passing error only from my server side

Comment: You can pass from server to client return Json(new { success = false,UnSelectedId=yourid }) and can get on client side as json.UnSelectedId

Comment: thank you i fully finished. but in last line retun null we not need but when i remove the line error show the "action result must be return" how to solve this?

Comment: replace with return Json(new {  });

Comment: Its does not hit anything in jquery?

Comment: ken-clark Thank you for you more suggestion . I didn't check my code because my server problem. ill back inform to with in 2hr . Thank you once again